# Call AS3-Parents function from AS2-Child

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

My parent ActionScript3 file has functions like these:

```
package  
{

    *lots of import.*

    public class Tabu extends MovieClip
    {


        public function callMe(name:String) {
            trace("callme");
        }

        public function setPage(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            if (e.target.name == "btn_1")
                changePage("campana.swf");
            if (e.target.name == "btn_2")
                changePage("toma_tabu.swf");
            else if (e.target.name == "btn_3")
                veranoPage("verano.swf");
            else if (e.target.name == "btn_4")
                changePage("manda_tu_tabu.swf");
            else if (e.target.name == "btn_0")
                changePage("home_1_v2.swf");
        }
```

I need to call the `setPage()` function from a ActionScript2 child that has been loaded within the ActionScript3 file.

In AS3, it's being called like this:

```
btn_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, (parent as MovieClip).setPage)
```

In ActionScript2, tried the following for both `setPage()` and `callMe()`, but none works:

```
on(release){
    parent.setPage();
    this.parent.setPage();
    _root.parent.setPage();
    _parent.setPage();
    this._parent.setPage();
    _root._parent.setPage();
}
```

I'm starting to think it can't be done at all. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LocalConnection](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html), but communication between AVM1 and AVM2 movies can be tricky.  Don't try to solve this yourself, use [SWFBridge](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/07/swfbridge%5Feasie.html).

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on the page I linked to?